# QGIS plugin external libraries in plugin’s directory

Tags: qgis, python, pyqgis, pandas, couchdb

I’m developing my first QGIS plugin and I have to use two external libraries not included in the default OSGeoW64 installation: *Couchdb* and *Pandas*.

I would like to include those libraries in my plugin’s directory so that users don’t have to deal with the installation of them.

So I created a folder called `lib`, inserted in it an empty `_init_.py` and downloaded in it the libraries using pip:

```
python3 -m pip install -t lib couchdb
```

The directory looks like this:

```
mhyconos
|--- lib
     |--- bin
     |--- couchdb 
     |--- CouchDB-1.2.dist-info
     |--- _init_.py
|--- _init_.py
|--- mhyconos.py
...
```

In `mhyconos.py` I imported couchdb using

```
from lib import couchdb
```

but when I install the plugin, this is what happens:

[image]

What am I doing wrong?